# Why is Jenkins Pipeline Artifactory Plugin outputting no artifacts to build-info?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jenkins-groovy

I am using Jenkins Pipeline to build, install and deploy a maven project, deploying to artifactory.
I use the Artifactory plugin for this, and mostly it is working really well.

However, in the scripted pipeline I need to get a hold of the URLs that the artifacts were deployed to. I would expect them to be placed inside the resulting buildInfo, but "artifacts" is always empty.

I have tried creating a new buildinfo manually, and then using it with `rtMaven run` function.

```
def rtBuildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
rtBuildInfo.name = "Something"
rtBuildInfo.number = env.BUILD_NUMBER
```

I have tried to create no manual buildInfo, and just running `rtMaven run`. Empty.

I have tried manually running `rtServer.publishBuildInfo rtBuildInfo` before and after deploy. Empty.

I have tried using `append` for the different buildInfo, and giving it manually as an argument to the different steps. Empty.

The files are definitely uploaded. I can see:
`[pool-9-thread-3] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoClientBuilder - [pool-9-thread-3] Deploying artifact: https://...`

In the log, and I can see the files uploaded inside Artifactory.

It does however also say in the log: `[main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Artifactory Build Info Recorder: publish build info set to false, build info will not be published...`
But I have found no way to set this to be done rather than calling on `rtServer.publishBuildInfo` as a separate step.

But when I print the buildInfo, it looks like this:

```
    "name": "Something",
    "artifacts": [

    ],
    "number": "68"
```

What do I have to do to get a buildInfo with "artifacts" filled with a list of entries with "localPath" and "remotePath" set?